# Laravel complex relationship many to many

Tags: laravel-5, many-to-many, relationship

I’m building a app in laravel and now I’m doing a payments resource.

The ideia is select many orders in the list to receive in same time. And in this receives can be used many type of payment (money, credit).

Now I has this tables order(id, total), paymentTypes(id, paymentName), payments(id, payment_type_id, value) and order_payments(order_id, payment_id).

This structure is more adequate to this situation?
And how can I get orders with all payments and the other orders payed together?

Any help is important.

Thanks everyone .

Answer (score 0):

> You Can Create Like This .This Might Help You
> First Create A Model Relationship In Order

```
public function order_payments(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderPayments::class, 'order_id', 'id')->with('payment');
}
```

> Then Go In 'OrderPayments' Model And Create A 'payment' name Relationship. That Relationship Has Join With Payment Table

```
public function payments(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Payments::class, 'id', 'payment_id');
}
```

> Then Go In 'Payments' Model And Create A 'payment_type' name Relationship. That Relationship Has Join With Payment Type Table

```
public function payment_type(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PaymentType::class, 'id', 'payment_type_id');
}
```